# Windows preload software before login

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I am a windows 10 user the only owner of this computer and even though I have a log in screen with password I would like to try to speed up the process of my computer.

Is it possible to "ask" windows to keep preloading software of my startup folder before the login takes place (I am the only available user) so to speed up the process? There are times that in between restarts you are not at your computer and when you are back after doing the login you need to wait again extra time for loading your software to take place.

I would like to thank you for your reply
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Yes. To do this, the program doesn't need to be in your startup folder, but rather, running as a service. That way, Windows will run it on startup, not logon. A good guide to do this can be found [here on How To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)

Comment: that sounds like a nice idea! Problem being that what I launch at startup is outlook and a virtual machine that both are not considered as services to pre run in background

Answer (score 2):

My computer loads all apps before I enter login pin code. 
Since I'm the only user of the computer, i replaced the password with pin code. Now when the computer starts, the lock windows appear. However, all apps completely load before I enter the pin code. I am not aware of doing anything special except changing login from password to pin.

Comment: That’s a new feature with the Fall Creator’s Update (1709).

Comment: More on that can be found in: [*Preloading user profiles in background - Microsoft Community*](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/preloading-user-profiles-in-background/00697550-d32d-4490-a10f-82bfd15ef09c "Preloading user profiles in background - Microsoft Community")

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to "pre-load" software, but you can set the computer to automatically log in after a restart so that it loads the software and programs before you get back. It's a bit of a risk in that the computer is sitting unlocked, but you could also set it to automatically lock after a short time. Programs should still load while the computer/account is locked.

Comment: another alternative will have to have in my computer two type of lock modes. When it is at my desk this can be the safest mode and thus computer not applying any locking scheme. When I move my computer to the unsafe mode then a 3 min lock should be needed. Can you have such variability?

Comment: I don't know of any way to have a one-button solution for that, but you could go into the screensaver settings and turn on/off the option to require a password when resuming. However, it's not as straightforward to get to the screensaver settings in Windows 10 as it was in Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

1. Disable credential request on login, so that the windows system will automatically log you in.
   run "netplwiz" and untick the "user must enter username and password..."
2. create a script that lock your station: (.bat or .ps file, so you can rename it from rescue disk if something goes wrong and your system goes to infinite loop of locking itself)
   C:> rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
3. Run the script In task Scheduler (Log-In event) or use logon script